# Error 500 install Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm installing Magento version 2.0.0 on my server. I am getting 500 error without even configure it. Try various solutions got no positive response. Apply the check and cleanup files and receive these messages:

Check :

```
Your server does not meet the following requirements in order to install Magento.
The following requirements failed, please contact your hosting provider in order to receive assistance with meeting the system requirements for Magento:

You need MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)

The following requirements were successfully met:
You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
Safe Mode is off
You have the curl extension
You have the dom extension
You have the gd extension
You have the hash extension
You have the iconv extension
You have the mcrypt extension
You have the pcre extension
You have the pdo extension
You have the pdo_mysql extension
You have the simplexml extension
```

Clean-up :

```
----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------

*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************
Setting all folder permissions to 755
Setting all file permissions to 644
Setting pear permissions to 550

****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************

************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder

------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:2.6845 seconds ------------------
```

At check file it says I do not have that version of MySQL on my server. Add the following code to see which version I have and this is the answer:

```
echo "<h2>Exact Version PHP & MySQL: </h2>";
printf("PHP version: %s\n", PHP_VERSION); 
$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'example'); 
#$mysql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
## Test the MySQL connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("</br> Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}
## Print the MySQL server version 
printf("</br> MySQL server version: %s\n",    mysqli_get_server_info($mysql)); 
##Close the MySQL connection 
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

Result :

```
Exact Version PHP & MySQL:

PHP version: 5.5.30-1~dotdeb+7.1 
MySQL server version: 5.6.15
```

**EDIT**

Error Logs my server

> [Fri Jan 08 12:02:44 2016] [error] [client 200.111.332.174] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.' in /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...')
>
> 1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...')
>
> 2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...')
>
> 3 /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...')
>
> 4 /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Fram in /home/nhernandez/public_html/editorialauncreemos/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 103

Comment: I there a close option for **Cannot be bothered to read the first 2 lines of the error** from the screen?

Comment: Except at the bottom where the OP lists "MySQL server version: 5.6.15". Curious. Unless the OP is not using localhost for the Magneto DB.

Comment: It will be obvious, but I do have a later version installed on my server.

Comment: Then he is not connecting to the same MYSQL in the install as he does in his PHP test

Comment: You can have, although it does lead to confusion, more than one MYSQL Server installed on any one system

Comment: Then, because the error would occur? Lei my server logs, I edit my post so you can see.

Comment: Have you tried with permission 777 on everything to start with ? (there might be some difference in files/folder permission if you use php as an apache module or as FPM) and also permission does not make it all, the user and group owning the file may differ from the one apache is launched on :)

Comment: 777 gave permission to all, now loads the web but without the css files, I do not have admin access.

Comment: CSS are now processed by LESS on Magento 2.0. This could maybe help : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

Comment: If he did, the problem is that I have access to the site administrator. enter the root / setup folder and configure the database and the data administrator, throws the admin URL but can not log in. @b.enoit.be

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the magento store loads after giving `777` permissions, we can conclude that there is no problem with mysql database connectivity.

Your server logs tell exactly what the problem really is. Make sure that the ownership of magento root directory, subdirectories and all files are as per apache (httpd.conf) `User` and `Group`.

In my box, User is `http` and Group is `http`. Issue following commands, where `$MAGENTO_ROOT` is your magento root directory:

```
$ chown http:http * -R
$ cd $MAGENTO_ROOT
$ sudo rm var/{cache,session,generation} -R
$ sudo -u http -g http bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ sudo -u http -g http bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you are using `php-fpm` then make sure `php-fpm.ini` has same `user` and `group` values.